# Show CheckBox column for Nullable<bool> properties in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

After some considerable searching I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue. I have successfully set the `DataSource` of a `DatagridView` using a list as follows.

The class

```
public class ChannelInfo
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DisplayName("ChannelId")]
    public int channelId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Channel")]
    public string sysName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Display Name")]
    public string dispName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Unit")]
    public string unit { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Divide By")]
    public int divideBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("YAxis")]
    public string yAxis { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Min Scale")]
    public int scaleMin { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Max Scale")]
    public int scaleMax { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Colour")]
    public string colour { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Set Point")]
    public double setPoint { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Limit(+/-)")]
    public double? limit { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("MKT")]
    public bool? IncludeInMKT { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ChannelInfo()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copy constructor to create a copy of another object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ci"> and object of the type ChannelInfo whos copy is to be created</param>
    public ChannelInfo(ChannelInfo ci)
    {
        channelId = ci.channelId;
        sysName = ci.sysName;
        dispName = ci.dispName;
        unit = ci.unit;
        divideBy = ci.divideBy;
        yAxis = ci.yAxis;
        scaleMin = ci.scaleMin;
        scaleMax = ci.scaleMax;
        colour = ci.colour;
        setPoint = ci.setPoint;
        limit = ci.limit;
        IncludeInMKT = ci.IncludeInMKT;
    }
}
```

setting the data-source of the grid

```
static List<ChannelInfo> chInfoList;
dgvChannels.DataSource = chInfoList;
```

The type of the final column of the data-grid is set to DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn using the designer.
The data-grid displays all the data fine except the last boolean field IncludeInMkt. It shows the text values (True/False) whereas, I expect it to be shown as a check box with the corresponding values in the chInfoList. I have also set the TrueValue to True and FalseValue to False in the designer.

Where am I going wrong, kindly suggest.

Comment: Should it be `bool?` or could it be `bool`     ?

Comment: It is a bool. as defined in the class shown in the post.

Comment: But in the post it's `bool?`  it's not `bool`. It means it allows null as well.  Is it the desired behavior?

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes its got to be bool? as we need it to be nullable while serialising and deserialising to and from our business objects. Is this causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView` will generate `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` for `bool` properties. But for `bool?` properties it will generate `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.

You can fix it in design-time or run-time by replacing the generated column with a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and setting its [`ThreeState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.threestate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property to true.

**Example - Show CheckBox for `Nullable<bool>` in DataGridView**

The following function replaces generated columns for `bool?` properties with tree-state check-box columns:

```
public void UseCheckBoxForNullableBool(DataGridView g)
{
    g.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
        .Where(x => x.ValueType == typeof(bool?))
        .ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            var index = x.Index;
            g.Columns.RemoveAt(index);
            var c = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            c.ValueType = x.ValueType;
            c.ThreeState = true;
            c.DataPropertyName = x.DataPropertyName;
            c.HeaderText = x.HeaderText;
            c.Name = x.Name;
            g.Columns.Insert(index, c);
        });
}
```

[image]

In above form, I've used the following model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public bool? MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

And applied the `UseCheckBoxForNullableBool` to change the generated column for `bool?` property to a tree-state check-box column:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<Test>() {
        new Test(){ MyProperty1 = 1, MyProperty2= null},
        new Test(){ MyProperty1 = 2, MyProperty2= true},
        new Test(){ MyProperty1 = 3, MyProperty2= false},
    };
    UseCheckBoxForNullableBool(dataGridView1);
}
```

Note: If you are interested to show `ComboBox` for `bool` or `bool?` columns, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40843518/3110834) which does the same for `bool` properties and change it a bit to support `bool?` as well.

Comment: Reza, thanks a lot for the prompt response. I shall try this out and if it works shall accept it as the answer.

Comment: No problem, take your time to test the code sample and let me know if you find any problem with the code.

Comment: It worked perfectly well. Thanks, accepting it as an answer now.

Comment: Cool! No problem :)