# Editing column header title in datagridview using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to edit column title in datagridview using Entity Framework. I added column and design name with form design, but when I add datasource in code, the columns with data appear in the left, and the columns I created with form design appear with blank. How can I use column design name to fill data from datasource?

I tried many things like

```
column[0].headercell.value = "column title"
```

but I don't want that. I want to use column design name.

Comment: You forgot to set the Columns' `DataPropertyName` (it can be set either in the Designer or at run-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem. I suggest that you could give up `datagridview1.DataSource=context.students.ToList()`.

If you only need to show the columns that you edited in winform, I recommend that you could use reflection and loop to do it.

Here is a code example you could refer to.

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Model1 model = new Model1();//DbContext
        foreach (var item in model.Students)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }
        var columns = dataGridView1.Columns;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            var names = model.Students.ToList().Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(columns[i].Name).GetValue(x)).ToList();
            for (int j = 0; j < names.Count(); j++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name].Value = names[j].ToString();

            }
        }
       
    }
```

Tested result(Only show the Id and Age column):
[image]

Comment: You should almost never give up setting DataSource. As mentioned in the first comment under the answer, if you set `DataPropertyName` for the column, then it will not be added again. Even if you want to only show a few of the columns, just add them, and set `AutogenerateColumns` to false, to prevent adding undesired columns. You can also decorate the property with `[Browsable(false)]` to prevent adding it.

Answer (score 1):

You should almost never give up setting DataSource.

As mentioned in the first comment under the answer, if you set [`DataPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) for the column, then it will not be added again after setting data source.

Even if you want to only show a few of the columns, just add them to the DataGridView columns collection, and make sure you set [`AutogenerateColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to false, to prevent adding undesired columns.

If you do not wan to add the columns manually or set the header texts manually, then you can decorate the property with [`[Browsable(false)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to prevent showing the column in DataGridView, and useing [`[DisplayName("The title")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) attribute to assign header text.

And finally you may be interested in the following posts:

- [DataAnnotations attributes for DataGridView in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885956/3110834)
- [DataAnnotation Attribute in Windows Forms - How to use UIHint Attribute with WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563841/3110834), an extension to my other answer to ad support for UIHint to specify column type.

[image]